# error: pasting "Java_com_my_packagename_myClass_myMethod" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token

Tags: c++, boost, precompiler

I'm writing a macro to make life easier by generating JNI method names, using the preprocessor:

```
#define JNI_WRAPPER_METHOD (className, methodName, returnValue, PARAMS) \
JNIEXPORT returnValue JNICALL Java_com_my_packagename_className_methodName\
(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, BOOST_PP_SEQ_ENUM(PARAMS))
```

so, ideally this:

```
JNI_WRAPPER_METHOD(myClass, myMethod, jint, (jint myInt)(jstring myString))
```

would translate to this:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_my_packagename_myClass_myMethod(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jint myInt, jstring myString)
```

However, the compiler throws the following error when I attempt to use my macro:

error: pasting "Java_com_my_packagename_myClass_myMethod" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token

Does anyone know why the macro fails?

Comment: Please learn about the `##` preprocessor concatenation operator. Or, if you want anything remotely sane, just avoid the preprocessor altogether.

Comment: I'm surprised it complained about *pasting* `"Java_com_my_packagename_myClass_myMethod"` and `"("`, since you don't have a token-pasting operator in your macro definition. Are you sure that's the exact code that produced that message?

Comment: Why? Why not use 'javap' as the designers intended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to concatenate strings like:

```
 Java_com_my_packagename_ ## className ## _ ## methodName
```

Also don't leave a space in the definition:

```
#define JNI_WRAPPER_METHOD(className, methodName, returnValue, PARAMS)
```

All in all, the following works fine:

```
#define JNI_WRAPPER_METHOD(className, methodName, returnValue, PARAMS) \
        JNIEXPORT returnValue JNICALL                                  \
        Java_com_my_packagename_ ## className ## _ ## methodName       \
        (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, BOOST_PP_SEQ_ENUM(PARAMS))
```